# Purchasing a larger display with the same resolution, concerned about screen space and benefits

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, external-display

I own an Acer E5-575G laptop. The screen is a 15-inch, 1920 by 1080 panel. The graphics card is an NVIDIA GEFORCE 940MX. I do a lot of things on my laptop: reading, writing, researching, browsing, coding, watching, gaming, and more.

I often find my screen to be too small and cluttered, especially when I am writing papers or doing programming projects. For this reason, I am considering purchasing a 24-inch external monitor for my desk. Unfortunately, as a student, my budget is small (under $200) and the only 24 inch displays in this price range have a resolution, like my laptop, of 1920 by 1080.

This brings us to my question. **With the same number of pixels, will I have the same problems that I have on my 15-inch screen, just larger? If so, are there other benefits to a larger display with the same resolution?** The best online information and discussions I could find focused mainly on the appearance or pixel size of different monitors, not the usefulness (or worthlessness, as the case may be) of a larger screen. I am *not* asking for shopping advice here, just some explanation.

Comment: The displayed content will be the same, but everything will be larger.  So if part of your problem was that small text was too small to read, that will be larger and easier to read.

Comment: Also consider that you can "extend your desktop" (in Windows parlance) onto the second monitor so you can actually have a total of twice as many pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching a bit different issue at the moment - why two screens of same resolution do not offer same desktop size - and that's how I ended up here.

My answer is empirical. I have Dell Inspiron 15R SE with FHD display (1920x1080) which is 15.6", and an external monitor Dell G2410 of same resolution but 24". G2410 offers about 40% bigger desktop area.

Obviously this has a lot to do with pixel density (PPI), but the exact explanation eludes me for now.

Anyway, the answer is: you will have more space on the external screen IN ADDITION to the icons and text being larger compared to laptop screen.

However, the quality of image between IPS type display of the Laptop and TN display of the external monitor cannot be compared. I actually feel physical discomfort when using the external screen and my eyes tire much more quickly, not to mention the accommodation issues when moving eyes from one to another.